# What device has high inductance? For example >1000mH (for 220Vrms 50-60Hz output)

Tags: datasheet, induction-motor, inductance, load, inductive

What devices have high inductance values (for example >1000mH?)

What I found in a real device (for example induction motor) datasheet is just near <1000mH (on rotor and stator.)

Is there anything that has high inductance value besides filters and chokes?

Comment: Well... what type of items have inductance....   Filters chokes... what else?  motors and the only reason you would go for high inductance is you need high turns

Comment: 1H isn't a high inductance. Real world coils for "high" voltages easily reach that. If you need inductances of 1 **kH** or such for a filter (for example), you can reach that size with a gyrator.

Comment: I do a research for my multilevel inverter with 220 Vrms 50 Hz output (only on simulation) with load variation and my lecturer said I need to simulate it first with R and RL load based on real device datasheet as much as possible

Comment: I recommend to use the values from a 220Vrms asynchronous machine with squirrel cage rotor then. That's a typical load for such an inverter. R depends on mechanical load for such a machine, and L you can find in its datasheet.

Comment: Yes there is. Output transformers in hi-fi valve amplifiers need a good low frequency response.